# Drag HTML element issue in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, safari, dialog, sortablejs

I have a dialog box, and inside that dialog, I have a list of items, every list item can be dragged and sort UI accordingly. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari, when I dragged the list item, it also dragged the some chunk of content present behind the dialog.

Here the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    #dialog {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 10%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      z-index: 999;
    }

    #sortable-list {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #sortable-list li {
      cursor: grab;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function openDialog() {
      const dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
      dialog.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function dragStart(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', event.target.textContent);
      event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    }

  </script>
  <button onclick="openDialog()">Open Dialog</button>

  <div id="dialog">
    <ul id="sortable-list" style="width:600px">
      <li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">Item 1</li>
      <li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">Item 2</li>
      <li draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- DUMMY DATA -->
  <p>
    The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
    sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```